# Why do many Base Class Library classes have Explicit Interface Implementation members?

Tags: c#, .net

MSDN: [System.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx)

Like the above link, many BCL classes in C# have Explicit Interface Implementations as class members.

I understand that when there is a name conflict between members of base interfaces we have to use Explicit Interface Implementations. But why do we have to use Explicit Interface Implementations in the above case? With which interfaces it there a name conflict?

Comment: You title complains that only a few BCL classes use explicit interface implementation, but your question body is saying that many BCL classes have it. Which is it?

Comment: The Type class is special.  These are mentioned because they are important to COM.  The _Type and _MemberInfo interfaces are [ComVisible] and important for custom CLR hosting.  It is normal to hide method implementations in COM.  AppDomain is another example.

Answer (score 2):

Explicit implementation of interfaces are used to hide instance properties/methods unless the calling code excplicitly asks for the interface.

This is useful in the following scenarios:

- The class author has deemed that the implementation of an interface is to be used in only rare cases and should be hidden by default for usability sake (this is clearly the case with the *Type* class as the explicit interface implementations are COM-specific)
- A class implements two or more interfaces that have common method/property signatures, but it's necessary to provide different implementations depending on the interface because the interfaces    have implicit yet differing behavioral contracts beyond the method signatures (the *Type* class also has an example of this; presumably the implementations of _MemberInfo.GetIDsOfNames and _Type.GetIDsOfNames share the same signature, but do different things depending on whether you cast a *Type* instance to a _MemberInfo interface versus a _Type interface).
- This has been used (although is discouraged) to have a class implement IDisposable so that an instance of it can be used in a *using* block, yet encourage callers to use a more domain-specific method for "disposing" the class when calling the method directly. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kimhamil/archive/2008/03/15/the-often-non-difference-between-close-and-dispose.aspx
- Can be use by API developers when they want a public class they're exposing to implement an interface of which the implementation should only be used within their assembly. In this case the interface would be declared with the *internal* keyword, and their public-facing class would explicitly implement the interface. The end result is that only code in their assembly can cast the instance of a class to the internal interface and access its implementation, while callers outside the assembly cannot.

Those are the use cases that come to mind; I'm sure there are others I haven't listed.